# How to make <li> list (horizontal) <ul> size in width?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

please help to solve this problem. I want to make <li> full size of <ul> (there is a space on the right side). Is see another way - to delete <ul> right padding (have no idea how to make it) and then add <li> width or just calculate and then add <li> width. (<ul> width / 5). But I don't find this way right because even if I can fit, it this will not be perfect fit. I'm sorry for my bad english : )

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

li {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
}

li a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 13px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Click</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please help me and explain if there is some mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can do that, by providing width to ```li```, ```width:calc(100%/5)%```. ```calc()``` is a great function offered by ```css3```.

Comment: Why not use flexbox?

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox and it will adjust the widths

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1;
}

li a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 13px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Click</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Click</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: PS: Better use `padding: 13px 0;` instead of `height: 100%`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I did not alter the OPs styles for the anchor

Comment: Sorry, forgot to  `@` mention OP